# KendoUI Angular 6.0.7 Charts Tooltip throwing Uncaught Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AnimationService -> AnimationBuilder]

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

Im trying to use tooltips on KendoUI's chart suite in our angular project but whenever I turn on tool tips it throws the following nasty error:

> ```
> Uncaught Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AnimationService -> AnimationBuilder]: 
> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AnimationService -> AnimationBuilder]: 
> NullInjectorError: No provider for AnimationBuilder!
> at 
> NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:1034)
> at resolveToken (core.js:1273)
> at tryResolveToken (core.js:1218)
> at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1113)
> at resolveToken (core.js:1273)
> at tryResolveToken (core.js:1218)
> at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1113)
> at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8168)
> at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:8856)
> at resolveDep
> ```

Following is how I've got my chart setup in html:

```html
 <kendo-chart class="chartStyling">
    <kendo-chart-axis-defaults [crosshair]="crosshair"></kendo-chart-axis-defaults>
    <kendo-chart-title text="Market Value Last Month"></kendo-chart-title>


    <kendo-chart-series>
        <kendo-chart-series-item type="area" color="#337AB7" [data]="seriesData" field="SellValue" categoryField="Date">
        </kendo-chart-series-item>
    </kendo-chart-series>

    <kendo-chart-value-axis>
        <kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
            <kendo-chart-value-axis-item-crosshair>
                <kendo-chart-value-axis-item-crosshair-tooltip>
                </kendo-chart-value-axis-item-crosshair-tooltip>
            </kendo-chart-value-axis-item-crosshair>
        </kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
    </kendo-chart-value-axis>
    <kendo-chart-category-axis>
        <kendo-chart-category-axis-item [baseUnit]="baseUnit" [maxDivisions]="10">
            <kendo-chart-category-axis-item-crosshair>
                <kendo-chart-category-axis-item-crosshair-tooltip>
                </kendo-chart-category-axis-item-crosshair-tooltip>
            </kendo-chart-category-axis-item-crosshair>
        </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
    </kendo-chart-category-axis>
</kendo-chart>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you haven't imported the BrowserAnimationsModule:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
...

@NgModule({
   imports:      [BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, ...]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```